# Qt C++ Задежка при отправке и получения запросов

Tags: c++, qt, сервер, клиент-сервер, client

Возникла такая проблема: Не могу сделать задержку при записи и считывании данных через QTcpSocket.

Есть Клиент и Сервер. Необходимо сделать обмен данными:

1. Клиент отправляет "Hello";
2. Сервер получает данные ("Hello") и выводит их через QDebug();
3. Сервер отправляет сообщение Клиенту: "Hello too";
4. Клиент получает данные ("Hello too") и выводит их через QDebug();
   И таких 3 (а может и больше) итерации (только с разными сообщениями) :)

Если использовать тупо:

1. pTcpSocket->write("Hello");       - Клиент
2. pTcpSocket->readAll("Hello");     - Сервер
3. pTcpSocket->write("Hello too");   - Сервер
4. pTcpSocket->readAll("Hello too"); - Клиент

То к сожалению, ничего не получается. То Сервер считывает пустую строку, то Клиент.... или вообще все смешивается. :(

Через:

```
 QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
 connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slotSendToServer()));
 timer->start(1000);
```

Работает адекватно, но я не могу отправлять разные сообщения (если только через какие-нибудь извилистые костыли).
Думал через функции Sleep(msec), но и так не работает;
Прошу Вас, подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно придумать? Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Сделайте сначала на С разберётесь с сокетами и тд. А уже потом трогайте qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте два приложения, подключите модуль `network` и последний стандарт C++

```
QT += network
CONFIG += c++latest
```

В функции `main` сервера:

```
QTcpServer serv;
if(Q_UNLIKELY(!serv.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 10050))) {
    qFatal("Выбери другой порт");
}
QObject::connect(&serv, &QTcpServer::newConnection, [&serv]{
    QTcpSocket* client { serv.nextPendingConnection() };
    QObject::connect(client, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [client] {
        QString msg { client->readAll() };
        qInfo() << "Клиент:" <<  msg;
        if(msg == "Привет") {
            client->write("Да, алё");
        }
        else if(msg == "Ну как там с деньгами") {
            client->write("Какими деньгами");
        }
        else if(msg == "Ну которые я внес в капитал") {
            client->write("Куда?");
        }
        else if(msg == "В капитал прожиточного минимума") {
            client->write("Ты пьяный или кто, сынок");
        }
        else if(msg == "Я Михал Палыч Терентьев") {
            client->write("Кто такой");
        }
        else if(msg == "Кто такой") {
            client->write("Пьяный");
        }
        else if(msg == "Пьяный") {
            client->write("Вот именно, ну и все, завяжи лямку");
            client->close();
        }
        client->waitForBytesWritten();
    });
});
```

В функции `main` клиента:

```
QTcpSocket client;
QObject::connect(&client, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [&client]{
    QString msg { client.readAll() };
    qInfo() << "Сервер:" << msg;
    if(msg == "Да, алё") {
        client.write("Ну как там с деньгами");
    }
    else if(msg == "Какими деньгами") {
        client.write("Ну которые я внес в капитал");
    }
    else if(msg == "Куда?") {
        client.write("В капитал прожиточного минимума");
    }
    else if(msg == "Ты пьяный или кто, сынок") {
        client.write("Я Михал Палыч Терентьев");
    }
    else if(msg == "Кто такой") {
        client.write("Пьяный");
    }
    client.waitForBytesWritten();
});
client.connectToHost("localhost", 10050);
if( Q_UNLIKELY(!client.waitForConnected())) {
    qFatal("Не дозвонился");
}
client.write("Привет");
```

Обратите внимание на `waitForBytesWritten()`, которая блокирует выход из функции до завершения записи сообщения в сокет.
Более развернутый пример [тут](https://github.com/oxaide/Qt-tcp-client-server)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)

Comment: А как можно использовать глобальные переменные в этих функциях?? 
например:
`if(msg == "Да, алё") {
/*тут добавить функцию создания сообщения createmsg(msg) , где msg глобальная переменная*/       
 client.write("Ну как там с деньгами");
    }`

Comment: @MaxDen объявить ее глобально, вне `main` в моём случае, и использовать внутри лямбда-функций как хочется.

Comment: я попытался добавить `QTcpSocket client` в .h файл. Но к сожалению это не сработало... :(

Comment: @MaxDen не сработало это что значит?

Comment: пока Вам вопрос писал, ответ сам пришел в голову))) Спасибо Вам большое

Comment: все таки вопрос появился:) Расскажите пожалуйста, как определить что этот диалог (который вы привели в пример) клиента с сервером завершился и можно отправлять уже другие данные?

Comment: Т.е пока последнее сообщение от сервера не пришло, то новые данные отправлять нельзя. Например, вот идет диалог, и после сообщения от сервера "Успешно". Отправляется другое сообщение. Пока обмен (по вашему коду) не произошел до конца - новые данные отправлять НЕЛЬЗЯ

Comment: @MaxDen ну вот вы с другом общаетесь - как определить, когда и что надо говорить? Пример выше можете изменить как угодно. Сообщения можете хранить в массиве, сравнивать пришедшие от клиента/сервера и отвечать в зависимости от того, что пришло. Молчит - значит еще что-то отправить, запрашивает - отправить что просит.  Ограничивается лишь вашей фантазией.

Comment: Не, Вы меня неправильно поняли. Я создал класс Auth. В нем создал метод `bool AUTH::auth(QTcpSocket **client_1)`. Из класса Client вызываю этот метод `QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket(); auth(&client);` А после вызываю метод write из класса Client. Полный код выглядит так:
   `QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket();
    AUTH cl;
        cl.auth(&client))
    client->write("cool");`
Проблема в том что ваш диалог не успевает завершиться и вместе с "Привет" отправляется и "cool". Как сделать, так чтобы сначала ваш код сработал а потом отправилось сообщение "cool"? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Просто хочется сделать, так, чтоб приложение не продолжило выполнять код пока от сервера не пришло ключевое слово. Например, "Все готово". Вот никак и не могу понять, как это реализовать?(

Comment: @MaxDen мой пример - это мой пример, и только. Он показывает, как можно передавать данные по tcp-соединению. Какое общение  вы хотите у себя сделать я не знаю. Создайте отдельный вопрос с конкретной проблемой.